Pandasonic way to combine multiple columns with expected format
There's a dataframe X with "Year", "Month" and "Day" as integer below,
  Year Month Day A B C ...
0 2020    10  10 ...
1 2021     1   1 ...
2 2022     1  10 ...
3 2023    10   1 ...
...


There's another dataframe Y with "Date" as string or datetime to be transformed from X, while other columns keep intact. The format is expected to be "YYYY-MM-DD".
  Date       A B C ...
0 2020-10-10 ...
1 2021-01-01 ...
2 2022-01-10 ...
3 2023-10-01 ...
...

What's the Pandasonic way to make it through, ideally in 1liner ?

your data is not reproducible

A possible solution:
df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: f'{x.iloc[0]}-{(x.iloc[1]).zfill(2)}-{(x.iloc[2]).zfill(2)}', axis=1)

Or a more vectorized approach:
df.iloc[:, 0].astype(str) + '-' + df.iloc[:, 1].astype(str).str.zfill(2) + '-' + df.iloc[:, 2].astype(str).str.zfill(2)


Alternatively, as suggested by @sammywemmy below -- thanks!:
df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(f'{x.iloc[0]}-{x.iloc[1]}-{x.iloc[2]}'), axis=1)

Or even:
df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, 'Year':'Day']))

Output:
0    2020-10-10
1    2021-01-01
2    2022-01-10
3    2023-10-01
dtype: object


pd.to_datetime() should work fine, if you pass the columns as is('year','month','day') link - so something like df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, 'Year':'Day'])

Thanks @sammywemmy @PaulS! I'd complete the 1liner : Y =  X.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(X.loc[:, 'Year':'Day'])).reindex(columns=['Date']+X.columns[3:-1].tolist()).
